# What SQL user to use for the connection string?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security

I’m using .Net 3.5 and SQL Server 2008 Express.

Should I use the administrator user for the connection string,

Or should I create a new user with limited permissions?

If I need to create a new user for the connection string:

What security permissions should I grant him?

How do I set those permissions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must definitely create a specific SQL login, which you will use for database hits in your application.

Access only to the database it uses.

Assign specific write/read permissions according to the logic you have.

Answer (score 1):

Never use Admin users account. Decide what all permission is required by your application then create the user based on that. I dont work mostly with SQl servers but I don't think there is a definite rule for this. It depends on application and the situation.

if the application is used to display only records then grand only read access.

Please check this post too

[Enterprise Connection String Management in ASP.NET - Best Practice?](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2004/05/11/129941.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

never use the sysadmin (sa) account - EVER!! create a new account, probably start with a member of the Public group, which is the default and then work from there.

Also, do not embed the pwd in the connection string - rather make it part of a config file; not only is it more secure, it's easier to manage.

In fact, you should really store the entire connection string in a config file.